# Qt4.8 build mysql, odbc and sqlite2 issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt4

im building a small static qt library using VS2010, unfortunately, mysql got this error: `c:\qtstatic\src\sql\kernel\../drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(52) : fatal error C1083
: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory`. how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have mysql installed? If yes, check where it's header files are.

Comment: Its mean i have to has mysql installed in my computer?

Comment: In GNU/Linux, it installed as dependency by package manger. Under Windows, probably Qt packed with all dependencies. I would suggst you to try find on your filesystem `mysql.h`. If it fails, then you need install it separately. If you find it, configure include paths in your compiler.